# I want select one item in custom listview and that item will get display on textview of second activity

Tags: listview, android-intent, android-activity, textview, onitemclick

I have used a custom ListView in my program and I want select one item in listview and that item will get displayed on textview of second activity.

My code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String lvalue= itemArrayList.toString();
        Intent intent=new Intent(Home.this,Liner.class);
        intent.putExtra(String.valueOf(listView),lvalue);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please specify your problem

Answer (score 0):

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()

{

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    String lvalue = (listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
    Intent intent=new Intent(Home.this,Liner.class);
    intent.putExtra("name",lvalue);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

});